# How to pipe processing fields by regex and json in Google Ops Agent?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pipeline, fluent-bit, google-cloud-ops-agent

`/etc/google-cloud-ops-agent/config.yaml`

```yaml
logging:
  receivers:
    app:
      type: files
      include_paths: [/www/app-*.log]
  processors:
    monolog:
      type: parse_regex
      field: message
      regex: "^\[(?<time>[^\]]+)\]\s+(?<environment>\w+)\.(?<severity>\w+):\s+(?<msg>.*?)(?<context>{.*})?\s*$"
    context:
      type: parse_json
      field: context
  service:
    pipelines:
      default_pipeline:
        receivers: [app]
        processors: [monolog,context]
```

I am trying to configure the `pipeline` so that:

- first, cut out the appropriate fragments in flat text
- then format one of those fragments as *JSON*.

However, it doesn't work. The resulting log only contains the *JSON* from this chunk, it drops all other data. What am I doing wrong? How to solve it? *Fluentbit* documentation does not help and *Google* documentation is minimum information.

Comment: Same issue - I posted to their GitHub after getting nowhere in the documentation: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ops-agent/issues/650

Answer (score 0):

I have VMs running docker compose images on Google Cloud. The containers spit out logs at `/var/log/syslog` in the following format (and thats the way they are sent to Logs Explorer (formely Stack Driver):

```
Mar  8 20:32:12 service-instance-beta-f14506b-1 docker[4020]: service-cron-beta-3    | {"message":"subscribing: TASK_CANCELLATION_BETA_CRON_SUB","severity":"INFO","timestamp":{"seconds":1709929932,"nanos":973725672}}
```

Then, I went out to build a regex that works for structuring that log entry into json format. I tested it on https://rubular.com and it works:

> The REGEX: `^(?<timestamp>\w{3}\s+\d{1,2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s(?<host>[\w-]+)\s[\w-]+\[\d+\]:\s(?<service>[\w-]+)\s+\|\s(?<message>{.*})$`

[image]

How it works on the config?

First, I use a processor of type `parse_regex` to process and structure my flat log entry in a structured json format.

Then, I use another processor of type `parse_json` to collect that structured json and inject it into the `jsonPayload` object of the StackDriver log entry.

This is the final working configuration:

```
logging:
  receivers:
    syslog:
      type: files
      include_paths:
      - /var/log/syslog
  processors:
    extract_json:
      type: parse_regex
      field: message
      regex: "/^(?<timestamp>\w{3}\s+\d{1,2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s(?<host>[\w-]+)\s[\w-]+\[\d+\]:\s(?<service>[\w-]+)\s+\|\s(?<message>{.*})$/"
    parse_message:
      type: parse_json
      field: message
  service:
    pipelines:
      default_pipeline:
        receivers: [syslog]
        processors: [extract_json,parse_message]
```